# clustered data analysis using mixed model

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, biostatistics, clinical-trials

our data has 5 treatment groups at 5 different time points. We want to use mixed model to see the different effect between the 5 groups, also at different time points.

The problem is, our data is clusters, i.e. each patient has 4 or more treatment sites, so the data can be considered clustered, with each patient as a cluster, and the cluster size of 4, 5 or more. The data from each site within the same patient should be correlated.

So, when we analyze the data, can we just take the mean result of all the sites from the same patient, to make one observation per patient? In this case, a 5x5 ANOVA (5 treatment groups against 5 time points) may work.

Or shall we use the individual site's result from each patient, in the format of X(i,j), i means the ith patient and j means the jth site in the ith patient? 
The sample size will be at least 4 times of the patient number. But, is it possible to analyze the data this way?

Any comments, hints, suggestion are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: After reading some papers, I think analyzing the data without averaging is the best way. Taking mean leads to loss of some information. Hope to get some comments

Comment: In this case a possible problem is that taking the mean discards the information about the cluster size and the averaged observations will be assigned the same weights. E.g., if you get an average of 4.5 from both cluster 1 and cluster 2, these two values will have the same weight in the model, even if cluster 2 is ten times bigger. However, if the cluster sizes don't vary much in your case, averaging can be ok.